# didReceiveMemoryWarning - manually unload views?

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management

There are times when didReceiveMemoryWarning gets called, but viewDidUnload does not. In my situation I would like to force viewDidUnload when didReceiveMemoryWarning gets called.

I can say this:

```
[self viewDidUnload];
```

But will that really unload the views? There is no self "unloadView".

Comment: The UIViewController will check if it is actually safe to unloaded it and set the view outlet to nil in didReceiveMemoryWarning. If the view doesn't get unloaded is probably unsafe to do so. Another option might be that [super didReceiveMemoryWarning] is not getting called in your custom implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? As long as you remember to call `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` (assuming you implement the method at all), UIViewController automatically unloads its view if its view has no superview. If this process does not happen, that generally indicates that the view is still part of a view hierarchy and it's not safe to unload.

In the rather unlikely case that you really do need to manually unload a view, you can do so simply by saying `self.view = nil`.

Comment: self.view does indeed unload the view, but how can you get it back?

Comment: `self.view = nil` unloads it. The next time anyone calls `self.view` it'll be re-loaded. Note, this means don't call `self.view` unless you really want the view to be loaded. You can use `[self isViewLoaded]` before calling that to avoid reloading the view in places where you'd prefer it to stay unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test my viewDidUnload code, I did this

```
-(void)forceUnload {
    NSLog(@"forceUnload.enter");
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@"forceUnload.leave");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've performed extensive logging and breakpoint setting investigating if `didReceiveMemoryWarning` unloads the view when a `UIViewController` is not the `visibleViewController`. The results: a `UIViewController`'s `view` **does not get unloaded** *(tested using ARC in a `UINavigationController`-based project)*. You need to set `self.view` to nil yourself, and **it will get reloaded** when `self.view` is called again. Even logging `self.view` will reinitialize it— use `isViewLoaded` to test if it's loaded rather than checking the property for `nil`.

```
#define String(fmt,...) [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt,__VA_ARGS__]
#define NSStringFromBOOL(aBool) String(@"%@", aBool?@"YES":@"NO")
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); //-[ViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    if (![self.navigationController.visibleViewController isEqual:self])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromBOOL(self.isViewLoaded)); //YES
        self.view = nil;
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromBOOL(self.isViewLoaded)); //NO
    }
}
```